# Apache POI date locale error using =now() formula

Tags: java, excel, date, apache-poi, locale

So I was trying to read excel file using POI using java, all was well and good until the date showed up. 
The excel file is a template which I cannot change and the date in it uses **=now()** formula.

When I look in the cell format the locale is set to [**English India.**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/veupx.png) 
This messes up the time conversion for example
**16-03-2018 becomes 2015-11-17** [check this.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2hgR.png)

The only solution that I found out by trial and error was the code works only if I change the locale to **English US**

[Download the Excel file](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1FVFAMrnxW0_w8WeooENuLhmqRukwmapP/view?usp=sharing")

[And here is how it looks in my system (Locale India).](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MTKwD.png)

**Snippet**

```
    case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:

                    SimpleDateFormat DtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                    System.out.println(DtFormat.format(date));
                    break;
```

**Full java Code**

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException
{
    String excelFilePath = "C:\\Users\\oi309\\Documents\\Projects\\AOI\\AOI Standard Format1.xlsx";
    FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File(excelFilePath));

    Workbook workbook = null;

    if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xlsx"))
    {
        workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
    else if (excelFilePath.endsWith("xls"))
    {
        workbook = new HSSFWorkbook(inputStream);
    }
    else
    {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("The specified file is not Excel file");
    }

    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
    {
        Row nextRow = iterator.next();
        Iterator<Cell> cellIterator = nextRow.cellIterator();

        while (cellIterator.hasNext())
        {
            Cell cell = cellIterator.next();

            if (cell.getCellType() != Cell.CELL_TYPE_BLANK)
            {

                switch (cell.getCellType())
                {

                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_STRING:
                    if (!cell.getStringCellValue().contains("NVS"))

                        System.out.print(cell.getStringCellValue());
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_FORMULA:

                    SimpleDateFormat DtFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
                    Date date = cell.getDateCellValue();
                    System.out.println(DtFormat.format(date));
                    break;
                case Cell.CELL_TYPE_NUMERIC:

                    System.out.print(cell.getNumericCellValue());
                    break;

                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println();

    }

    workbook.close();
    inputStream.close();
}
```

Thankyou in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The  problem you are facing has nothing to do with the cell format or the locale. The cell value stored in the file along to the formula `=NOW()` is:

```
<c r="B4" s="5"><f ca="1">NOW()</f><v>42325.30892476852</v></c>
```

and this is 2015-11-17 (exactly 11/17/2015 07:24:51 AM). This is the date value `apache poi` will read from the file without reevaluation the formula.

And if you look at the document properties (`/docProps/core.xml`), you find:

```
<dcterms:modified xsi:type="dcterms:W3CDTF">2015-11-17T13:25:31Z</dcterms:modified>
```

So 2015-11-17 was the date on which this file was last time opened in `Excel` and recalculated. At this date the date of `=NOW()` was 2015-11-17.

So I suspect this file is a template, created 2015-11-17, and then filled with values outside `Excel` and without recalculation. If you are opening this file in `Excel`, the `=NOW()` will be recalculated as it is a volatile function. And then the date will be the current date.  If you then resave the file without further changings, then the cell value stored in the file along to the formula `=NOW()` is current datetime also. After this `apache poi` will read this  date.

So for reading this file using `apache poi` without opening and resaving in `Excel` before, reevaluation the formula is needed. Simplest way:

```
...
    workbook.getCreationHelper().createFormulaEvaluator().evaluateAll();

    Sheet firstSheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
    Iterator<Row> iterator = firstSheet.iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext())
...
```

Please read [Formula Evaluation](https://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/eval.html) about other possibilities for evaluating formulas using `apache poi`.

Comment: Thank you, Axel, evaluateAll() is working. It might be the issue in excel file itself.